# Hide notification bar when incoming call in android

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-notification-bar

When phone state is ringing, I want to run an activity to show my own screen.

I'm using:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

and

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

but notification bar does not hide when activity is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Go through following code snippets:

1. Create a BroadCastReceiver Class to listen to incoming calls with
   the highest priority:

   **`Manifest.xml`**:

   ```
   <receiver android:name=".MyPhoneBroadcastReceiver">
       <intent-filter android:priority="99999">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
2. Then in class, `onReceive()` method opens the `CustomCallsReceiver` Activity with intent action is **`"android.intent.action.ANSWER"`**

   ```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

   Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

   if (extras != null) {

       String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);          
       final String incomingNumber = extras.getString("incoming_number");

       Handler callActionHandler = new Handler();

       Runnable runRingingActivity = new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run() {
                //Notice the intent, cos u will add intent filter for your class(CustomCallsReceiver)
               Intent intentPhoneCall = new Intent("android.intent.action.ANSWER");
               intentPhoneCall.putExtra("INCOMING_NUM", incomingNumber);
               intentPhoneCall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               context.startActivity(intentPhoneCall);
           }
       };
       if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
           //increase the delay amount if problem occur something like -the screen didn't show up- that's the key about this method(the delay).
           callActionHandler.postDelayed(runRingingActivity, 100);    
       }
       if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
           callActionHandler.removeCallbacks(runRingingActivity);
       }

   }
   }
   ```
3. Add this intent filter in to `manifest file` for the class you will
   use as a Custom call receiver.

   ```
       <activity android:name="CustomCallsReceiver" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       </intent-filter>    
   </activity>
   ```
4. The `CustomeCallsReceiver` Class:

   ```
   public class CustomCallsReceiver extends Activity {

    private String TAG = "CustomCallsReceiver";
    String incomingNumber, caller;

    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.custome_calls_receiver);

   TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
   number.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

   incomingNumber = getIntent().getExtras().getString("INCOMING_NUM");
   caller = getCallerName(incomingNumber);

   if (caller != null) {
       number.setText(caller + "\n" + incomingNumber);  }  
           }
   ```
5. And finally of course don't forget to add the Theme for not title or
   notification bar at the `manifest` file

   ```
    <application
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
   ```

Hope this working for you...

Comment: tanks,but i create thread like this:  public void run(){
          Intent i = new Intent();
          i.setClass(con, Call.class);...} and activity show correctly but notification bar in many times show in activity(sometimes hidden)!